# How to block inconsistent floating point inputs using Haskell Parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm assigned to make a rather simple calculator parser using Haskell Parser Combinators (namely, by importing Parsec.Text). This parser needs to operate both over integer and floating point inputs. There is an essential code to introduce into the matter of what I'm looking for:

```
import Text.Parsec hiding(digit)
import Data.Functor

type Parser a = Parsec String () a

digit :: Parser Char
digit = oneOf ['0'..'9']

number :: Parser Integer
number = read <$> many1 digit

fp_char :: Parser String 
fp_char = many1 digit

fp_number :: Parser Double
fp_number = read <$> parser where
    parser = (++) <$> fp_char <*> (option "" $ (:) <$> char '.' <*> fp_char)   

addition :: Parser Integer
addition = do
    lhv <- number
    spaces
    char '+'
    spaces
    rhv <- number
    return $ lhv + rhv

fp_addition :: Parser Double
addition = do
    lhv <- fp_number
    spaces
    char '+'
    spaces
    rhv <- fp_number
    return $ lhv + rhv
```

So, there is a case I'm stumbled at: how to block fp input like instances here:

```
"123h.578" "600.w57"
```

Both to be considered as error triggers, but in the code above it turns out to accepting a part of false input: in fact parser casts away a wrong character like a letter once occurring it, following characters are eiminated too. So, the problem appears as same or similar inputs remain valid input data, even though it goes partially. My solution has to do with such a function:

```
isValidInput :: Parser String -> Bool
isValidInput (x:xs) = if x `elem` ['0'..'9'] then isValidInput xs else False
```

It doesn't work due to an inappropriate type resulted from `isValidInput`. What's more, I miss understanding how to use this auxiliary code adding it to core calculation functions, let say to fp_addition given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, Parsec parsers **should** be written to consume a valid prefix of the input stream and stop at the first character they don't recognize.

So, the string `"123h.578"` should be successfully parsed by `fp_number` or `number` because the prefix `"123"` is acceptable input for those parsers.  So, your existing parsers `fp_number` and `number` have the correct behavior:

```
> parseTest fp_number "123h.578"
123.0      -- this is correct
> parseTest number "123h.578"
123        -- this is also correct
```

Checking for this invalid `h` character should take place at a higher level.  Normally, you will have a top-level parser that tries to parse the entire stream and uses the `eof` parser to ensure that no unparseable characters remain.  For example, the parser:

```
fp_expression :: Parser Double
fp_expression =
  (try fp_addition <|> fp_number) <* eof
```

will parse these:

```
> parseTest fp_expression "123+0.578"
123.578
> parseTest fp_expression "123.578"
123.578
```

while rejecting your other examples:

```
> parseTest fp_expression "123h.578"
parse error at (line 1, column 4):
unexpected 'h'
expecting "." or end of input
> parseTest fp_expression "600.w57"
parse error at (line 1, column 5):
unexpected "w"
```

You should not need an explicit `isValidInput` function.  If you were to define one, it would probably be implemented by running a parser like `fp_expression` to see if it does or doesn't succeed in parsing the entire stream.

Also, you might find it helpful to study [this tutorial](http://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/).  Working through the chapter on "Very simple expression parsing" will help you quite a bit in learning the far-from-obvious basics of writing this kind of parser.

Comment: Really robust answer, thank you. I gonna improve my comprehension using tutorial referred by you.